# Why the express module is not installing in its default directory e.g., npm\node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to install express module using the following commands:

```
npm install --save express
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator
```

After installation I was expecting the module to be created inside **nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules**, Instead it is getting installed and created in somewhere else (In **C:\Users\$SudoName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**).

Therefore while running the project node is unable to locate the express module in it's own directory where it suppose to be.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain your commands step by step:

```
$ npm install --save express
```

The --save command is used when you want to save a package for distribution. This command saves the package under your **dependencies** section of your *package.json* file.

```
$ npm install -g express
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install): "In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.".

In your case: *C:\Users\$SudoName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules*

**Note**: You can see where your packages are installed using:

```
$ npm list -g
```

Finally,

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
```

gets the same approach. It gets installed under your global dependencies.

Comment: nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules is a directory for npm itself to work :)

Comment: @javiergarval, node installs the module locally (i.e., in your working dir) when you don't specify **--global/-g**. If global included in the command it'll install and place the module into directory where node's installed. Please let me know if I'm on the same page.

Comment: @AnubhavSrivastava If we install any package globally it is going to go inside the npm/node_modules folder, this is what you're saying right? My global express install is not getting stored on the npm dir.